# Delete list elements in python (preprocessing tokenized tweet)

Tags: python, list, twitter, preprocessor, element

I have a list something like list below:

`tbul=['"','Mustang','\\','u456','has','great','\\','u743','power','.','"']`

This is actually the tweet I accessed it from twitter. Tokenized it. Now I have it in list.

Result I want is

`tbul=['Mustang','has','great','power']`

So that I can apply sentiment analysis on it.

How do I remove `./']\` and utf-8 codes from the list containing tokenized tweet.

Code I tried is (I tried both del and remove function but does not work )

```
atz=0
for atz in (0,len(tbulla)-1):
print atz
if ((tbul[atz]==':') or (tbul[atz]==',') or (tbul[atz]=='.') or (tbul[atz]=='/') or (tbul[atz]==';') or (tbul[atz]=='"') or (tbul[atz]=='[') or (tbul[atz]==']') or (tbul[atz]=='{') or (tbul[atz]=='}') or (tbul[atz]=='-') or (tbul[atz]=='\\')):
    del tbul[atz]
    #tbulla.remove(tbul[atz])
atz=atz+1
```

Result I get after using this is same as earlier and atz value changes to equal to len(tbul)

Comment: Is that actually the string `"u456"` (that is, the letters `u`, `4`, `5` and `6`) and the like, or is it `"\u0456"` (that is, a len 1 unicode character)? And is this Py2 or Py3?

Comment: I accessed a tweet and it was like ' " Mustang \u456 has great \u743 power. " ' After this I tokenized it and passed the value to tbul list. After that I got the above mentioned tbul array and I am using Py2.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `filter` function.

```
>>> forbidden = r':,./\"[{()}]'
>>> tbul=['"','Mustang','\\','u456','has','great','\\','u743','power','.','"']
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x in forbidden, tbul))
['"', '\\', '\\', '.', '"']
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x not in forbidden, tbul))
['Mustang', 'u456', 'has', 'great', 'u743', 'power']
```

`forbidden` would be a list of any of the characters you dont want.

You can also use `re`:

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = re.compile(r'[\w]+')
>>> tbul=['"','Mustang','\\','u456','has','great','\\','u743','power','.','"']
>>> list(filter(lambda x: pat.match(x), tbul))
['Mustang', 'u456', 'has', 'great', 'u743', 'power']
```

which uses a pattern which will only match a collection of `\w` characters, which is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (all upper/lower case letters, numbers, and underscores)

Comment: Please don't recommend `filter` when you'd end up using a `lambda` to make it work. In CPython, generator expressions and list comprehensions can do the same work faster and more flexibly in every case where the `filter` predicate isn't a CPython built-in implemented in C.

Comment: That said, neither of these cases required a `lambda` (and it's part of why I frown on using `lambda`; people use it unnecessarily). In particular, `filter(lambda x: pat.match(x), tbul)` is just a slow/verbose version of `filter(pat.match, tbul)`. And while admittedly ugly, if you needed speed, `itertools.filterfalse(forbidden.__contains__, tbul)` is a faster version of `filter(lambda x: x not in forbidden, tbul)`. If you didn't need _all_ the speed, I'd just use `(x for x in tbul if x not in forbidden)` (which is readable, and within 10% of best speed).

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you need [`regex`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). But why do you need to remove the utf-8 codes? What if a word has an accented character? For now I will presue you want to remove all utf-8 characters:

```
import re

tbulla = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]|u\d{3}', '', ' '.join(tbul)).split()
```

`r'[^\w\s]'` -> matches any non ascii character (in Python 2 otherwise utf-8 for Python 3) or whitespce. These are replaced by `''`, i.e. removed.

I will amend if your use turns out to be different.

Comment: As written, it looks like the "codes" may be just strings describing the character, not len 1 strings with a single ordinal in them. I asked for clarification in the comments; if it's just regular strings of `u` followed by 3 numbers, then this wouldn't deal with it, because without the separation in the `list`, `u456` wouldn't be recognized separately from any other word.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "codes" are just `u` followed by three digits, a slight improvement of existing code:

```
import re

# Bound method to reject u### entries
iscode = re.compile(r'^u\d{3}$').match
# Convert to frozenset to avoid rejecting len 2+ punctuation runs by accident
forbidden = frozenset(r':,./\"[{()}]')

# Replace tbul with new list w/o forbidden values
tbul = [x for x in tbul if x not in forbidden and not iscode(x)]
# If tbul must be mutated in place (e.g. received as an argument,
# and you want to change caller), assign to empty slice:
tbul[:] = [x for x in tbul if x not in forbidden and not iscode(x)]
```